# open downloading file in new window or tab

Tags: php, joomla, download, joomla2.5, meta-tags

I’m doing a joomla component programming. I need to open my downloading file in new tab. the code for file download is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3;URL=http://localhost/joomla/images/uploads/<?php echo $filee; ?> " >
```

I used this code instead of `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filee."");`
is that I need to display some messages on the page in between the form submission and start of download. header wont allow that.

the download works well with meta but instead of opening the file in current window how can I open it in new tab.??
I tried by giving form tags with target=_blank before this meta tag but no use.

Comment: With Joomla, I wouldn't use meta tags for a file download. Is the download generated from a form or button?

Comment: @Lodder: yes sir.a user can download any file only after filling up a form. i use an if condition to check if form submit or not.then inside that i wrote some thanks messages and the above download meta code.

Comment: once the form has been submitted, redirect the user to the download file, don't use a meta tag

Comment: i use this code sir echo '<script>window.open("http://localhost/joomla/images/uploads/'.$filee.'","_blank");</script>';    is there any pblm in using this code? it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you are going to open in an new window or tab is to remove the redirect and add a link to the file on your thank you page with target="_blank".

Comment: thanks for ur response sir. but i need to start the download automatically showing the message. how can i do that?

Comment: The javascript from your comment above is the only way that is going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

After many search,I implement the Idea  to Download pdf file in new window after redirect request to other page in four steps-

```
1). Session::flash('myfileNameThatStoredInDb',  $orders->order_invoice);
```

2). Create a function in controller with the following codes

```
public function pdfDownload($image_url){

        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($image_url) . "\"");
        readfile(\Url('storage').'/invoice'.'/'.$image_url); 
    }
```

3). Create Route for the above method.

```
Route::get('/pdfdownload/{url}',"OrderController@pdfDownload");
```

4). check the Session and get its value in html file  tags and append it to the your Controller's method path

```
@if(Session::has('download.in.the.next.request'))    
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url={{ asset('pdfdownload/'.Session::get('download.in.the.next.request')) }}">
    @endif
```

Note-> This code is working perfectly in Laravel, My Purpose is just to give an Idea.
Thanks